# Deserialize & Serialize Session Data Object Stored in a Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, json.net

I'm trying to store session data in a cookie.  The idea is to store the object, which is pretty small, as a json string in a cookie.  I'm using a modified version of a class example found in an answer in this thread:

[Is this technique of ASP.NET session access multi-user-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413432/is-this-technique-of-asp-net-session-access-multi-user-safe)

Here's what I'm trying...

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web;

namespace SomeNameSpace
{
public class MySession
{
    // private constructor
    private MySession()
    {
        SomeString = string.Empty;
        MyDate = DateTime.Now;
        UserId = 0;
    }

    // Gets the current session.
    public static MySession Current
    {
        get
        {
            MySession session = null;
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Session"].Value != null)
            {
                // This is where I'm having trouble.  Neither of these work:
                session = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MySession>(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Session"].Value);
                session = (MySession)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Session"].Value);
            }

            if (session == null)
            {
                session = new MySession();
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["Session"].Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);
            }
            return session;

        }
    }

    public string SomeString { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
}
```

This line:

```
session = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MySession>(HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["Session"].Value);
```

Does not throw an error. But the problem is, it kicks off the constructor, and so it always returns the object with the default values.

This line:

```
session = (MySession)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["Session"].Value);
```

Throws an error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to type 'SomeNameSpace.MySession'
```

How do I get this done?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reading the *response* cookie of key "Session", which is never set at that point. You need to read the *request* cookie.

That being said, if this is session data, you don't want to store it in user-readable and user-editable cookies.

Comment: I understand the risk of keeping session data in a cookie.  There won't be anything in this data that is sensitive.  The problem is, the app keeps dropping session data when it's stored as an actual session variable, and this is causing a lot of problems.

All that being said, I get the same error when using Request.

Comment: _"the app keeps dropping session data when it's stored as an actual session variable"_ - then you'll have the same problem when using cookies. Investigate the source of that problem and all your issues will go away. The problem with the code you posted is solved by my answer, and that you never check the _request_ cookies and thus always end up with a newly initialized session object. You probably have some kind of load balancer or other issue that eats your cookies.

Comment: See the edits in the OP.  I changed Response to Request, but still see the exact same results. No change.

Comment: @CaseyCrookston You may need to configure your server so that it sends  the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header, and also ensure whatever is making requests to your server has cookie credentials enabled as well. (If it's the same problem I was experiencing recently...)